# Webpack-dev-server serves a directory list instead of the app page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, reactjs-flux, webpack-dev-server

[image]

I can only see the actual app under `/public`.

The configs in `webpack.config.js` are below:

```
var path    = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './app/js/App.js'
],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
     ]
   },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]

};
```

The project hierarchy is:

- app

  - js
- node_modules
- public

  - css
  - img

  bundle.js

  index.html
- package.json
- webpack.config.js

How can I modify to make sure the `http://localhost:8080/` entry is for the application per se?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you're using webpack's dev server you can pass in options to use `/public` as a base directory.

```
devServer: {
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true
},
```

See the [webpack configuration docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/), and specifically the [webpack dev server docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver) for more options and general information.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it got me unstuck. Also thanks for posting the links to both documentations.

Comment: What about webpack 2? I read the docs and couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: @mightyiam you're going to want to set publicPath property as well. I'll update to answer to include that.

Comment: I don't know how anyone could figure this out from the documentation. Thank you. Perhaps consider rewriting some of the documentation on those properties?

Answer (score 21):

You can also add the `--content-base` flag to your start-up script, e.g.

```
    "scripts": {
        "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base ./public"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I misspelled `'index.html'` when I set up the `HTMLWebpackPlugin`. Double check your filenames if you're using this plugin.

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});
```

Comment: this helped me to fix the fact that I was getting an autogenerated HTML by webpack. Now, by setting this `template` param I can specify my own html with no problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is quite hard to debug, any tip to check what final path are used by webpack-dev-server?

Answer (score 1):

I had accidently removed index.html and then I got only the directory list.